# cypress log request from interceptor

Tags: cypress, interceptor, cypress-intercept

How can I log a "request.body" from cypress interceptor.
Here is the code

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.log("---- -- Running beforeEach");
    cy.intercept("POST", "/graphql", (req) => {
      cy.log("-- --- -- loging from interceptor", req.body);
      return req;
    });
  });
```

I get this error :

> Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

If I remove cy.log no errors are raised.
So how can I log this?  This runs on CI.

Will use https://github.com/flotwig/cypress-log-to-output
plugin if no other way.

Comment: I would try `req.continue()` instead of `return req` -- is there a specific reason you are returning the request?

Comment: either return or req.continue()  the issue persists. It is the  cy.log within the interceptor that is causing the error.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to use the synchronous [Cypress.log](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-log#Examples) instead

```js
cy.intercept("POST", "/graphql", (req) => {
  Cypress.log({ displayName: 'Request body', message: req.body })
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

One way you can access the request body would be using [cy.should() callback](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Function) as follows. First you define your intercept command and add an alias to it:

```js
// intercept some post request
cy.intercept('POST', '/api/**').as('yourPostRequest');
```

After that, you append `cy.should()` with callback function to the `cy.wait()` command which allows you to access and log the request body like:

```js
// wait and log request body
cy.wait('@yourPostRequest').should(($obj) => {
  const requestBody = $obj.request.body;
  cy.log(requestBody);
});
```

You can also find more helpful information regarding network calls and Cypress in [this blog post](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/12/23/asserting-network-calls-from-cypress-tests/).